# regex: match multiple lines until a line contains

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
foo.a = [10
20
30
40];

foo.b = 'foobar';
```

I am using the [`foo\.[ab]\s*=` regex](https://regex101.com/r/lR9kN2/1).

I try to match all the lines that follow until a line contains a certain character.

The first match should cover everything except of the last line, because that line contains an equal sign. I tried a lot of things with (negative) lookahead, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: [`foo\.[ab]\s*=[\s\S]*?;`](https://regex101.com/r/lR9kN2/2)???

Comment: nope the semi colon is optional

Comment: `foo\.[ab]\s*=[\S\s]*[=]+` Something like this? Where exactly is the match supposed to stop at?

Comment: Try [`(foo\.[a-zA-Z])\s*=\s*([^=]+?)(?=$|\n.*=)`](https://regex101.com/r/hW4fK8/2)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
foo\.[ab][\s\S]*?(?=\n.*?=|$)
```

- `[\s\S]*?` matches [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) any character
- `(?=\n.*?=|$)` until a newline containing an `=` is ahead or `$` end.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wU7zB2/3)

Comment: this doesn't capture the second definition

Comment: @simon after the amazing edit, it sure does. more importantly for my use case, it was easy to modify if i just wanted to do what's in the title: **regex: match multiple lines until a line contains**: `foo[\s\S]*?(?=\n.*?30)` for instance.

Comment: yeah initially it didn't, but after the edit, i accepted this as the correct answer, so obviously it does the job.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to match lets say `30` as a group? I mean to match some group that's in `[\s\S]*?` part

Comment: @CRONUS Sure, probably best to extract from the matched blocks in another step.

Comment: There's no another step. Trying to figure out PHP Storm's Ideolog message pattern :)

Answer (score 6):

## Variation 1

```
foo\.[ab]\s*=[\s\S]*?(?=foo\.[ab]\s*=)
```

It matches what you want up until another `foo.a =` or `foo.b =` using a positive lookahead.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xV9wL4/2

## Variation 2

```
(foo\.[ab]\s*=)[\s\S]*?(?=(?1))
```

This works the same as above but using a capturing group and a reference to that capturing group (by `(?1)`) to simplify it down

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xV9wL4/3

Comment: both variations don't capture the second definition